# Finishing Contextual Action Bar on CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and when the user long-presses on any particular item, the CAB starts.

I am using,

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

and the MultiChoiceModeListener to intercept the callbacks,

```
getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                    long id, boolean checked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Now, in my onResume() (outside this listener), I want to check if my ActionMode is visible/invisible and if it is, then depending upon certain conditions, I want to manually disable/enable it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I waited for a day but didn't get any answer on this and solved it myself. I don't know if the approach is perfect.

Declare a field ActionMode

```
ActionMode mActionMode;
```

Now in the onCreateActionMode() method you get the ActionMode,

```
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mActionMode = mode;
}
```

And in the onDestroyActionMode(),

```
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    mActionMode = null;
}
```

Now anywhere in your code just check if the mActionMode is null or not to check if the ActionMode is enabled or disabled.

Hope this helps. Do post an answer if you have a better solution.